# Bernoulli trials calculation

Tags: probability

Consider n independent bernoulli trials with p (H)=p and p(t)=q for all trials. Let S be the random variable that gives the number of heads in n trials. Let A be the average random variable = s/n.
What is the mean and variance for one bernoulli trials

I'm not sure how to approach this

Comment: Have you tried using the definition of the variance?

Comment: How do I approach?

Comment: Henry gave you hints below, with the definition of the variance.

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

- One Bernoulli trial
- So $n=1$
- and $A=S$, which is $1$ with probability $p$, and $0$ with probability $q=1-p$
- Finding $\mathbb{E}[A]$ is very easy,
- $\mathbb{E}[A^2]$ almost as easy,
- $\text{Var}(A)=\mathbb{E}[A^2] - (\mathbb{E}[A])^2$